# software centre cant find the internet

Tags: networking, software-center, vmware

I am running ubuntu 11.04 on vmware. I can access the internet fine with firefox but the Software Centre cant download anything and tells me to check my internet connection.

Using apt-get on the command line gives me errors like...

```
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-security/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.176 80]
```

Synaptic also reports similar problems.

Any ideas what is going wrong?

Comment: `404 Not found` tells you that the server could be contacted but **the server** said: "not found" - so it is not a networking problem and neither one of vmware.

Answer (score 0):

To install updates, you need to have a supported version of Ubuntu. 11.04 is no longer supported, so you cannot update it. You need to upgrade your installation to fix this. Just start a Terminal session and type `sudo do-release-upgrade` to upgrade to the latest version of Ubuntu.